# why does posterior prediction involve integration over all parameter space?

Tags: bayesian, inference

The primary objective of Bayesian inference is to compute the posterior.

For instance, if the posterior $p(\theta | x)$ is known then the expectation $\mathbb{E}$ of the test function $\tau(x)$ under the posterior $p(\theta | x)$ can be computed like

$E[\tau | x] = \int d\theta \tau(\theta) p(\theta | x)$.

To make a prediction $x'$ from the data distribution $p(x | \theta)$, assuming $x'$ and $x$ are independent to each other, the posterior predictive distribution of $x'$ is

$p(x' | x) = \int d\theta p(x' | x, \theta) p(\theta | x) = \int d\theta p(x' | \theta) p(\theta | x)$.

How should I convince myself on an intuitive level the necessity for the integration over all $\theta$ in order to compute the predictive posterior?

Comment: It might help if you say what your intuition thinks the alternative is. Using the posterior mode? Integrating over part of the posterior? Having a direct model for $p(x'|x)$ (eg, I rolled these dice yesterday and left them in a locked office, they should still add up to 11)?

Comment: $\theta$ here acts as a nuance parameter of a model and to integrate over all such parameters is key to Bayesian inference and learning as the parameter space acts like hypotheses space and you need to take all of them into account. It’s different from maximum a posterior (MAP) learning or maximum likelihood learning.

Comment: This is the only *coherent* way to incorporate the uncertainty about $\theta$ given the actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), etc.  These laws follow directly from the definition of conditional probability and conditional probability densities.  If you would like to convince yourself of the validity of these rules then I recommend you review the definition and properties of conditional probability densities.